# How to fill data in ngTable using ngResource but search and sort without hitting API call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable, ngresource

I have a ngTable in which I want to fill the data when the controller is using ngResource to query the API call to get the response **array**.

**Service** *(used same in both cases)*

```
angular.module('core.template.block').
        factory('TemplateBlockFactory', ['$resource', 
            function($resource) {
                return $resource('http://api/', {}, {

                });   
            }
        ]);
```

**Case 1**:

```
angular.module('temp').component('tempB', {
    templateUrl: 'template/B/tempB.template.html',
    controller: ['TemplateBlockFactory', 'NgTableParams'], 
        function TemplateBCtrlr(TemplateBlockFactory, NgTableParams) {
            var self = this;
            var tableData = [];
            tableData = TemplateBlockFactory.query();
            self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {dataset: tableData});
        }
})
```

**Case 2**:

```
angular.module('temp').component('tempB', {
    templateUrl: 'template/B/tempB.template.html',
    controller: ['TemplateBlockFactory', 'NgTableParams'], 
        function TemplateBCtrlr(TemplateBlockFactory, NgTableParams) {
            var self = this;
            self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
                getData: function (params) {
                    return TemplateBlockFactory.query();
                }
            });
        }
})
```

**Template**

```
        <div class="box-body">
            <table ng-table="$ctrl.tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-striped" show-filter="true">
                <tr ng-repeat="block in $data">
                    <td data-title="'#'" filter="{ id: 'number'}" sortable="'id'">{{ $index+1 }}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{ name: 'text'}" sortable="'name'">{{ block.name }}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Width'" filter="{ width: 'number'}" sortable="'width'">{{ block.width }}</td>
                    <td data-title="'Height'" filter="{ height: 'number'}" sortable="'height'">{{ block.height }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**In Case1**, when I am opening the destination page then **table remains empty** and when I click on any sorting button then table data appears (It searches and sorts in the data stored in `tableData` variable which is used in `dataset` attribute of NgTableParams)

**In Case2**, when I am opening the destination page the table is filled with all the data as desired but when I am sorting/searching it is again hitting the API server which is not desired as I have very less data to show in this case (that's why I was trying to use `dataset` attribute rather than `getData` function attribute but it's not showing data at page load)

**-------EDIT-------**

1. Case 1 solved, by using `self.tableParams.reload();` when query is completed so I changed,

   `tableData = TemplateBlockFactory.query();`

to

```
tableData = TemplateBlockFactory.query({}, 
                function(data) { 
                    self.tableParams.reload(); 
                });
```